# How to stop a process which was started with task scheduler

Tags: java, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a .bat file which has command to run a Java console program.

I created windows scheduler task to invoke the bat file.

When I run the windows task then it invokes the java program, but when I stop the windows task (Right click the task, Select option **End**) then my java program do not stop.

My question is how to stop an external program which got started from the bat file. Is there way to capture the **End** event/signal from task which can be passed to bat file or java program to stop the program.

I got similar question here https://superuser.com/questions/1054534/stopping-a-scheduled-task-with-a-batch-file-action-doesnt-stop-the-program-runn 
but it is unanswered.

Atul

Comment: What is the content of your batch file? Also, if the program is started via a Scheduled Task, it may have been run under system or admin privileges, therefore it's likely that you'd need to  end it with the same privileges. On StackOverflow, in order to help we need specifics, currently you have not provided those to the degree required, for a solution.

Comment: There are couple of variable which we are setting, followed by triggering java program Java -jar <path of jar file>.

Comment: Also interested in solution. It's properly killing the process on one Windows 10 machine but not killing it on another Windows 10 machine. Incredible